# Trying to use fetch to get data from backend

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to fetch data from the backend, but I get a weird error. If anyone has a clue how to fix please help.

My code

```js
  async componentDidMount() {
    const url = 'http://localhost:8080/zoom';
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(data)
  }
```

Error:

```
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8080/zoom' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

Comment: Maybe you'll find your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43262121/trying-to-use-fetch-and-pass-in-mode-no-cors?rq=1). Either way this question has been asked before a few times. Basically the browser blocks cross-origin responses unless you specify the CORS headers in the response.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a 'weird' error. It's a security measurement.

[See this to understand what is CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

Since you are using Port 3000, I assume that you are using NodeJS (with Express) for backend server.

You can [install cors package from NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) and use it to allow your front-end domain (in this case it is localhost:8080) for Cross Origin Resource Sharing.

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();

const corsOptions = {
    origin: 'http://localhost:8080',
    optionsSuccessStatus: 200
  }

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because of your origin domain is not whitelisted. Instead of adding an additional `cors` package and also cors sometimes may not work, so you can whitelist your selected domains, which means that you are giving entire access to your backend.

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
var allowedOrigins = ["http://localhost:3000"];
var origin = req.headers.origin;
if(allowedOrigins.indexOf(origin) > -1){
   res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', origin);
}
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
next();
});
```