# FormData() object is empty in console during POST

Tags: javascript, fetch, form-data

this question has been asked before but I couldn't find the answer in another question. when I log my formdata I just get {} i am sending two items that are text and one image file from my client html using fetch

my form

```html
 <form id="addform">

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">post</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" placeholder="article title">
        <textarea type="text" class="form-control bigbox" id="body" placeholder=""></textarea>

        <input type="file" id="image" placeholder="image" name="imageFile">
      </div>

      <button id="addpost" type="submit"class="btn btn-primary">add Post</button>
    </form>
```

postdata function

```js
 async function postData(url = '', data) {

  // Default options are marked with *
  const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
    mode: 'no-cors', // no-cors, *cors, same-origin
    cache: 'no-cache', // *default , no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
    credentials: 'same-origin', // include, *same-origin, omit
    headers: {
      //'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    redirect: 'follow', // manual, *follow, error
    referrerPolicy: 'no-referrer', // no-referrer, *no-referrer-when-downgrade, origin, origin-when-cross-origin, same-origin, strict-origin, strict-origin-when-cross-origin, unsafe-url
    body: JSON.stringify(data) // body data type must match "Content-Type" header
  });
  return response.json(); // parses JSON response into native JavaScript objects
}
```

sending the request with a form object

```js
document.getElementById("addpost").addEventListener('click',function(e){
      e.preventDefault()
      let form = document.getElementById('addform')
      let formdata = new FormData(form)
      formdata.append('title',document.getElementById("title").value)
      formdata.append('body',document.getElementById("body").value)
      formdata.append('imageFile',document.getElementById("image").files[0])    

      postData(`http://${window.location.hostname}:3000/admin/addpost`,formdata)
      .then((data)=>{console.log(data.data)})
    })
```

what i get in my XHR preview in chrome

```
{}
```

I'm not sure why this is happening it just seems to not be grabbing the form values at all

Comment: You're not logging your `FormData` anywhere and even then, why would you. If you want to do debugging, use your browser's debugger. The only `console.log()` line in your code above is `console.log(data.data)` and since you've set `mode: 'no-cors'`, you won't be able to read any response data

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to use fetch and pass in mode: no-cors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43262121/trying-to-use-fetch-and-pass-in-mode-no-cors)

Comment: @Phil no-cors should block the front end to access the response,  it shouldn't block the request's content. And OP talked about the Network console, not the js one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't stringify your FormData, send it directly, and don't set the request headers, let the browser handle that too:

```
  const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
    mode: 'no-cors', // you probably don't want this... let the default "cors"
    cache: 'no-cache', // not sure why you'd want that either...
    credentials: 'same-origin', // include, *same-origin, omit
// removed the Headers, the browser knows how to talk to a server, that's hos job.
    redirect: 'follow', // manual, *follow, error
    referrerPolicy: 'no-referrer', // no-referrer, *no-referrer-when-downgrade, origin, origin-when-cross-origin, same-origin, strict-origin, strict-origin-when-cross-origin, unsafe-url
    body: data // pass directly the FormData here
  });
```

And note that you don't have to, and probably even shouldn't set all the options of the fetch, just use the defaults, in 99% of cases that's what you need.

Comment: @monsterpiece the `body: JSON.stringify(data)` part was the biggest problem.