# How to display the response of fetch in chrome dev tools console?

Tags: google-chrome, fetch

The following is what I see see pasted elseshere but only shows the promise, want the full response data or the exception.

```
fetch('http://localhost:8000/data/random?m=2&n=3', {mode: 'no-cors'}).then(res => res.text()).then(console.log)

Promise {<pending>}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to use fetch and pass in mode: no-cors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43262121/trying-to-use-fetch-and-pass-in-mode-no-cors)

Comment: See the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/43268098/441757

Comment: Yeah, basically sounds like you can't do it without changing the settings on the dev server (serving the original client app to the browser) if I understand things?

Comment: So I guess the real question is if there is an easy "local console" for chrome. Like a default vanilla page you just open to start messing around in.