# Problem when request News API with Java Script fetch command run command from the google chrome console

Tags: javascript

**Code :**

```
async function getNews() {
    const response = await fetch('http://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=in&pageSize=1&apiKey=a876816f98574cdfa23ffdc7d531c7bc');
    const jsonResp = await response.json();
    return jsonResp;
}

n = await getNews();
```

**Error Shown In Google Chrome Console:**

> Access to fetch at
> 'http://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=in&pageSize=1&apiKey=a876816f98574cdfa23ffdc7d531c7bc'
> from origin 'chrome-search://local-ntp' has been blocked by CORS
> policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the
> requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the
> request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
>
> GET http://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines
> country=in&pageSize=1&apiKey=a876816f98574cdfa23ffdc7d531c7bc
> net::ERR_FAILED getNews @ VM88:2 (anonymous) @ VM94:1
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to fetch

[link to error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0B64v.png)

Comment: Change the protocol from http to https and check , it says the request from browser are not allowed

Comment: you seem to be hitting this url from your dev system, and API might have blocked the localhost server calls.  try hitting this by deploying on some cloud server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CORS are generally fixed by setting response headers at server side something like below

```
 res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
 res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
```

But temporary you can use chrome CORS plugin to get data from other host

Comment: Thank you for your response. From where I put this chunks of codes?

Comment: this has to be set at server side for response header, it seems you are using some 3rd party API(http://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines) where you do not have any control. Try installing Allow CORS: Access-Control-Allow-Origin - Google Chrome plugin

Answer (score 0):

Try using `https://newsapi.org` instead of `http://newsapi.org` as the endpoint.

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43262121/trying-to-use-fetch-and-pass-in-mode-no-cors

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But after replaced http with https , I get new error :
{status: "error", code: "corsNotAllowed", 
message: "Requests from the browser are not allowed on the Developer plan, except from localhost."}

code: "corsNotAllowed"

message: "Requests from the browser are not allowed on the Developer plan, except from localhost."

status: "error"

__proto__: Object