# How to read a json file hosted in another site using react

Tags: reactjs

I'm tryng to get a list of data from another website, but i keep getting the error:

> dataFetcher.ts:7 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of
> input

this is the code I am using:

```
return await fetch('http://otherwebsite.com/export/export.json',  { mode: 'no-cors' } )
    .then((res) => res.json());
```

What am I missing? (when I inspect the data im retrieving everything looks normal)

Comment: Try this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43262121/trying-to-use-fetch-and-pass-in-mode-no-cors

Comment: I see you have `{mode: 'no-cors' }` in your options - if this is in fact a `CORS` issue, you won't be able to do to anything about it.

Comment: Remove the mode options and pass the proxy url before your mentioned url. As mentioned in this link :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43262121/trying-to-use-fetch-and-pass-in-mode-no-cors

Comment: thanks that did solve the problem. but why do I need a proxy if the data is public?

Comment: `CORS` has nothing to do with whether the data is public or not - read about `CORS` here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A request with `mode: no-cors` returns a opaque response, which is not readable.

See here:
[Trying to use fetch and pass in mode: no-cors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43262121/trying-to-use-fetch-and-pass-in-mode-no-cors)

Comment: that did solve the problem. but why do I need a proxy if the data is public?