# How can I see if a webpage returns 404?

Tags: javascript, html, http-status-code-404

I was wondering how I could see if a website returns a 404 Error. I've heard of https://httpstatus.io/, but I don't think I can use it in JavaScript and for what I need (but if I can, please tell me . . .)

EXAMPLE: my site is tilier.com/hello, and I want to see if banana.co/banana returns a 404 error. How can I do this?

Also, my site is not actually tilier.com.

Comment: There is no simple way to do this if you are wanting to run this javascript in a web page. Would either need a third party service that is not CORS restricted or set up a proxy on your server that makes a HEAD request to the remote site

Comment: Basically the same answer as [the one I posted in reply to your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62722861/2485966). Just with a different URL.