# CORS issue on localhost express NodeJS server

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, fetch

I'm using fetch web API to send a post method request from reactJS to express NodeJS server both on localhost with different ports.

**Client Fetch API**

```
fetch("http://localhost:8081/test", 
{
            method: "post",
            mode:"no-cors",
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },        
            body: JSON.stringify({
                username : "John Doe",
                password : "It's a secret"
            })
}).then(function(response)
{
            if(response.ok)
            {
                return response.json();
            }else
            {
                console.log(response)
            }
}).then(function(body) { console.log(body); }).catch((error) => { console.log(error) });
```

**Server - Express NodeJS**

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cors = require('cors');

var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cors())

app.post('/test', function (req, res) 
{
  return res.send({ message: 'Any response' });
})
```

I receive my POST data from client with no issue, But i get no response from server. Almost tried everything but i get this error on response

```
body: (...)
bodyUsed: false
headers: Headers {}
ok: false
redirected: false
status: 0
statusText: ""
type: "opaque"
url: ""
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I'm sure that if you look in your chrome dev tool you get CORS Policy error, can you check please?

Comment: Have you tried with removed `mode:"no-cors",` ? Here you can read more on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43262121/trying-to-use-fetch-and-pass-in-mode-no-cors

Comment: Damn, @mehowthe, Man i appreciate you, Did not expect this one. You saved my day!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [@mehowthe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3061469/mehowthe), This issue was fixed by removing `mode:"no-cors"`