# why is the url malformed in get request with fetch API in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get the latitude and longitude from the geocoder API using fetch in js. [image] When I check the response , the url is malformed, and it prepend it with localhost.

```
const getLatLong = async () => {
        const response = await fetch(
            {
            url: 'https://geocoding.geo.census.gov/geocoder/locations/address?street=4600+Silver+Hill+Rd&city=Washington&state=DC&benchmark=2020&format=json;',
            mode: 'no-cors',
            method: "get",
                headers: {
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                    "Content-Type": "application/json"
                }
            });

        console.log(response);

        const myJson = await response.json(); //extract JSON from the http response
        console.log(myJson);
        // do something with myJson
    }
```

Comment: Do you know what `mode: "no-cors"` does? You won't be able to read the response if using that

Comment: `url` is not part of the `Request` init object. You should pass the URL in as the first parameter to `fetch()` instead. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch. Also `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is a **response** header; do not add it to your request headers. `GET` requests do not have a payload / body so do not need a `Content-type` header either

Comment: I have tried to pass the url as a seperate parameter , but then in the response it became blank.

Comment: Did you read [my first comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68010817/why-is-the-url-malformed-in-get-request-with-fetch-api-in-javascript?noredirect=1#comment120207857_68010817)?

Comment: Why do you have those 2 headers? You are sending a request, not a response.

Comment: It has to be "no-cors", if I use "cors" , I get  CORS  error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to use fetch and pass in mode: no-cors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43262121/trying-to-use-fetch-and-pass-in-mode-no-cors)

Answer (score -1):

I think you want something like this.

```js
const getLatLong = async() => {
  const response = await fetch("https://geocoding.geo.census.gov/geocoder/locations/address?street=4600+Silver+Hill+Rd&city=Washington&state=DC&benchmark=2020&format=json", {
    "headers": {
      "accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
      "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9,tr;q=0.8",
      "sec-ch-ua": "\" Not;A Brand\";v=\"99\", \"Google Chrome\";v=\"91\", \"Chromium\";v=\"91\"",
      "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
      "sec-fetch-dest": "document",
      "sec-fetch-mode": "navigate",
      "sec-fetch-site": "none",
      "sec-fetch-user": "?1",
      "upgrade-insecure-requests": "1"
    },
    "referrerPolicy": "strict-origin-when-cross-origin",
    "body": null,
    "method": "GET",
    "mode": "cors",
    "credentials": "include"
  });
  const myJson = await response.json(); //extract JSON from the http response
  console.log(myJson);
  // do something with myJson
}

getLatLong();
```

**Edit**: Oddly enough `fetch` only works in geocoding domain. I think this geocoding API has some problems or restrictions with CORS settings.

Comment: Maybe I should add that I'm using asp.net framework 4.8 and the url I get is redirected to "https://localhost:44302/Home/[object%20Object]