# If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to use firebase google authentication with my react app but it keeps giving me this error.

Access to fetch at 'https://apis.google.com/*/scs/apps-static/*/js/k=oz.gapi.en.OxsXq8UvEOs.O/m=gapi_iframes/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=AQ/rs=AGLTcCN7FQWUE2nltJhOBLbHOeQiriRsIg/cb=gapi.loaded_0' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

I know it has something to do with local host but i dont know how to solve it. Can anyone help me please.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/43268098/16732460 If you are doing fetch to the google URL it won't work, and show a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example if not

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.