# How to get a response without a endpoint in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, fetch

Here is the code I wrote:

```js
...
    await fetch('https://google.com', {
      method: "GET",
      mode: "no-cors"
    })
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response.body);
      console.log(response.status);
      return response.text();
    })
    .then((responseText) => {
      console.log(responseText);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error.toString());
    });
...
```

```
https://google.com (O)
https://google.com/test (X)
```

I want to get a response(HTML) from a URL with no endpoint. So I sent HTTP requests using the Fetch API, but it continues to return a null value.

Is there a way to solve this problem in the pure JS environment?

Comment: try removing `await`

Comment: What do you mean by "with no endpoint"?

Comment: seems like google just blocks you. you will get response from https://stackoverflow.com

Comment: check out response.type opaque https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-filtered-response-opaque

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to get a response(HTML) from a URL with no endpoint. So I sent HTTP requests using the Fetch API, but it continues to return a null value.

By using, `mode: "no-cors"` you get an opaque response and that can't be accessed with JavaScript.

So, as stated [here](https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/working-with-the-fetch-api), you should get a null value.

If a site, sends the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in its responses, only then frontend JavaScript code can directly access responses from that site.

And, the site (google) you are trying to access does not send that.

> Is there a way to solve this problem in the pure JS environment?

You can access responses from sites that allow it or configure your backend to send the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

For example this snippet works,

```js
async function testResponse() {
    let response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1');
    let json = await response.json()
    console.log(json)
}

testResponse()
```

However, if you want to access response from a site that does not allow it, `CORS proxy` might help.
Details available in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43262121/trying-to-use-fetch-and-pass-in-mode-no-cors/43268098#43268098) answer.

---

Also, `fetch` uses promised-based API. That means you can use it like this,

```js
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
.then( response => console.log(response) )
```

or,

```
async function test() {
    let response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1');
    console.log(response)
}

test()
```

No need to use both at the same time.