# How to handle and redirect when blocked by CORS policy occurs in React application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, fetch

I have a function that receives a result.text (this is a string from qr scan camera eg string:565650).
When i have the result i saved in const `productString`, and then i make a get request with that string. If the response is ok i have my product and adding it to my checkout-bag,until that spot everything is working perfectly.

Also when i will scan a non product - qr code which means my result.text will not get a response i want to redirect the user in a 404 page. In addition i get Cors policy error.

[image]

I want after my scan if is not successfull to redirect the user in 404 page my code is below in that function.

```
  const handleScanResult = (result) => {
    setLoading(true);
    setProductString(formatString(result.text))
    fetchData(`${API_URL}/products/${formatString(result.text)}`)
      .then((data) => {
        handleAddMemo(data);
        setLoading(false);
        setOpenAddMemoDialog(true);
        handleClose();
      })
      .catch((ex) => {
        setLoading(false);
        console.log(ex,"ex")
      })
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cors is a browser security mechanism, you cannot skip it... Well in fact you can try but you'll face issue, see [Trying to use fetch and pass in mode: no-cors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43262121/trying-to-use-fetch-and-pass-in-mode-no-cors)

I recommand you to follow the rules. So either:

- you server both app and api on the same host+port
- you put a proxy like nginx to serve both on same host+port
- you change your api to follow the needed rules, mostly headers and option method.

There is a good explanation here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Here is a simple config file for Nginx if you want to give it a try

```
    server_name myapp.localhost;

    listen 80;

    location /api/myApp {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:15000;
        #Change 15000 to the API port you use
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:17050;
        #Change 17050 to the APP port you use
    }
}
```