# empty response from rest api using javascript fetch method (got a Json response on Postman)

Tags: javascript, rest, fetch-api

Managed to get a JSON response in Postman, but got an empty response in the console, with no errors whatsoever.

here's the code:

```
function getFetch() {
  const url = `https://fantasy.premierleague.com/api/bootstrap-static/`;

  let requestOptions = {
    method: "GET",
    redirect: "follow",
    mode: 'no-cors',
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "x-requested-with"
  };

  fetch(
    "https://fantasy.premierleague.com/api/bootstrap-static/",
    requestOptions
  )
    .then((response) => response.text())
    .then((result) => console.log(result))
    .catch((error) => console.log("error", error));
}
```

P.S: I also get the JSON if I typed the URL in the browser. But not with a fetch

Comment: Why are you setting it to no-cors when you're clearly making a cross-origin request to a 3rd party api?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to use fetch and pass in mode: no-cors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43262121/trying-to-use-fetch-and-pass-in-mode-no-cors)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are trying that in browser, client-side:

1. Cross-origin `mode: 'no-cors'` requests have [no access to response body](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/mode) and headers, basically they blindly send data but cannot see the result.
2. Those [`Access-Control-…` headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Headers) are not for the request, but for the server response. If the server responded with them, the response would be readable from all origins. (Provided such requests were not self-restrained by `mode: no-cors` as describer above.)

You can see that no mater what you fetch, response is always with `status: 0` and `ok: false`:

```js
function runFetch() {
  console.clear();
  fetch(
      url.value, {
        mode: nocors.checked ? 'no-cors' : 'cors'
      },
    )
    .then((response) => {
      console.log('Response status:', response.status, ', OK:', response.ok);
      return response.text()
    })
    .then((result) => console.log("Result: »" + result + "«"))
    .catch((error) => console.log("error", error.message));
}

runFetch()
```

```html
<label>URL: <input id="url" value="https://fantasy.premierleague.com/api/bootstrap-static/" /></label>
<br><label>no-cors: <input type="checkbox" id="nocors" checked /></label>
<br><button onclick="runFetch()">run</button>
```