# Struggling to store .txt file in a variable as string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, text

I've tried the below:

```
const fs = require('fs');
var file = fs.readFileSync("../word.txt", {encoding: 'utf8'}).toString()
```

but get the error `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs'`. All I want is to be able to store all the .txt contents into a variable that I can manipulate. What other easy ways are there as I don't think there's any easy way to bypass this error.

Thanks a lot and please help!!

Comment: You can't access local files from a website. Imagine that you could read someone's entire file system if it would be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to load the contents of a text file that is either bundled with your React project or hosted separately.

1. Put the file in the [public folder](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/) and fetch it via direct URL.
2. Import the file which will use Webpack's [general asset module](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/#general-asset-type) to bundle and emit a URL you can load.
3. Host the file somewhere on the public internet on a server configured with [CORS access](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS). [AWS S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/cors.html) for example

Both approaches involve loading a URL. You could make a generic function to do so...

```js
const loadTextFile = async (url) => {
  const res = await fetch(url);
  if (!res.ok) {
    throw res;
  }
  return res.text();
};
```

and then load the content into a state value, eg

```js
const [word, setWord] = useState("");
```

#### Option #1 - *public folder*

```js
useEffect(() => {
  loadTextFile(process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/word.txt")
    .then(setWord)
    .catch(console.error);
}, []);
```

#### Option #2 - *asset*

```js
import fileUrl from "./path/to/word.txt";

// ...

useEffect(() => {
  loadTextFile(fileUrl)
    .then(setWord)
    .catch(console.error);
}, []);
```

#### Option #3 - *online*

```js
useEffect(() => {
  loadTextFile("https://example.com/word.txt")
    .then(setWord)
    .catch(console.error);
}, []);
```

[image: Edit peaceful-chaum-8k7l60]

---

#### Bonus round - custom webpack config

Customise your Webpack config to add a resource query to load modules using [source assets](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/#source-assets)

```js
module: {
  rules: [
  // ...
    {
      resourceQuery: /raw/,
      type: 'asset/source',
    }
  ]
},
```

and import your text file contents using

```js
import word from "./path/to/word.txt?raw";
```

If you're using `create-react-app`, this will require [ejecting](https://auth0.com/blog/how-to-configure-create-react-app/) your configuration.

---

#### The JSON option

If you don't mind encoding your text file content into a JSON string literal, you can always use a `.json` file.

For example, `assets/word.json`

```json
"this is some plain text in a JSON file"
```

```js
import jsonFileContents from "./assets/word.json";
```

Comment: Thanks so much mate, I have a lot to learn and I appreciate the detailed response. One other I approach I had was to store the .txt as a multiline string in a .js file and to then export it but that approach didn't feel good to me, yours is great!

Comment: @LevinKent oh, you can put the contents into a `.json` file and import that directly. I'll update my answer

Comment: Hey again @Phil, just wondering, is it possible in react to extract a .txt file from a Url i.e (https://github.com/itsfoss/text-files/blob/master/sherlock.txt) and store as a variable that can be passed in to the functions you've created above? Thanks again

Comment: @LevinKent absolutely. You just fetch the URL like you would any other online resource, using the exact same `loadTextFile` function as above. The server hosting the file would need to have CORS access configured though.

Comment: @LevinKent I've added an example to my answer... option #3

Comment: Thanks a bunch and yeah that makes sense, unfortunately, most .txt files don't work on my site due to the CORS access restriction. I'm going to try follow this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43262121/trying-to-use-fetch-and-pass-in-mode-no-cors to try bypass. Do you approve boss?

Comment: The answers on that question are good. Really the only option is to use a proxy