# req.body is blank in POST requests (Express node)

Tags: node.js, json, api, express, http

Server Code:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express() app.use(express.static('public')) app.use(express.json({limit :'100mb'}));
app.post('/post', (req, res) => { console.log('post called'); 
console.log(req.body);  ////Printed here
 })
app.listen(3000)
```

Client code:

> const data ={agent: 41}
> const options = {
> method: 'POST',
> mode: 'no-cors',
> credentials: 'same-origin',
> headers: {
> 'Content-Type': 'application/json'
> },
> body: JSON.stringify(data)
> };
>
> fetch('http://localhost:3000/post', options);

output in server terminal

[image]

can anyone please tell me what am i doing wrong, how can i get the value?

Expected Output :
{agent: 41}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On you client code, why are you using `mode: 'no-cors'` option?
Removing it will fix your problem.

```
const data = { agent: 41 }
const options = { method: 'POST', credentials: 'same-origin', headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }, body: JSON.stringify(data) };
fetch('http://localhost:3000/post', options);
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43262121/trying-to-use-fetch-and-pass-in-mode-no-cors) you can find an explaination on what is happening.

If you were using `mode: 'no-cors'` to handle a cors error, this is not the way to go. You should use the [cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) middleware in you Express based application.

```
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')
const app = express()
app.use(cors()) // use it as first middleware
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply its working now,I spent 12 hours thinking that the issue is with JSON Parsing.