# JavaScript Fetch API: Try to post data to a specific endpoint URL

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch

Try to parse the response body text as JSON (`response.json()`) and got this error in the console:

> Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input (at script.js:177:33)at postData (script.js:177:33)

This is the code that throw the error in the line of `.then(response => response.json())`.

```js
fetch('/', {
    method: 'POST', // or 'PUT'
    mode: 'no-cors',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    redirect: 'follow',
    referrerPolicy: 'origin-when-cross-origin',
    body: JSON.stringify({
      "email": emails.val()
    }),
  })
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => {
    console.log('Success:', data);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error('Error:', error);
  });
```

I expect it to post data (`emails.val()`) to the body of the endpoint so I can use the controller I wrote to take the data from this endpoint and insert it to model.

Comment: The response to the request is not valid JSON. Check the request in devtools to see what the responseText is, and debug it in your server side.

Comment: is your response actually returning proper json?

Comment: `mode: no-cors` is probably not what you want. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43262121/trying-to-use-fetch-and-pass-in-mode-no-cors

Comment: I tried to check the response before parsing it with "if (!response.ok) {
    throw Error(response.statusText);
} " it throwing error

Comment: Add the code where you "create" `emails`, where it gets `.val()` from. You input data isn't valid JSON. it never does the request so it never gets a response.

Comment: I think the error message is indicating that the json encountered the end of the input before it was able to fully parse the data but I'm not 100% sure how if it's related to async or defer problem in JS

Comment: This is the HTML: **<input type="email" class="email" placeholder="Enter your Email">** And this is the Js: where the val is from **const emails = $('.email');**

Comment: replace response.json() by response.text() just to see what you get?

Comment: replaced by response.text() and passed, Thanks! do you have an idea why it can't pass with json?