# i receive "TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource." message while trying to fetch django server with "PUT" method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, fetch-api

## My fetch function

```
const savePost = () => {
        fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/posts/${id}/edit`, {
            method: "PUT",
            mode: 'cors',
            
            headers: {
                "withCredentials": "true",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*',
                "Access-Control-Request-Method": "PUT",
                'Accept': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(post)
            
        }).catch(error => console.log(error))
```

## In DJANGO settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'corsheaders',
    ...
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    ...
]

CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = ['*']
```

I've already put CORS into my django settings.py and looked for a while to find how to solve this, but nothing helped. The main things i did is adding headers to fetch request and adding more CORS settings to django settings.py

I don't know how to fix this error, if you could help me, I would really appreciate this

Comment: Please add more information about your problem and your error. And check it maybe solve your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43262121/trying-to-use-fetch-and-pass-in-mode-no-cors