# React and PHP - CORS Error: MissingAllowOriginHeader

Tags: php, reactjs, cors

I am developing a todo app to work with React and PHP for the first time. I am using Apache(XAMPP).

App.js:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_ENDPOINT}`, {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({
        action: "todos",
      }),
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => setTodos(data));
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Todo App</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

index.php:

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

try {
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=todo", "mustafa", "12345");
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die($e->getMessage());
}

$action = $_POST['action'];

switch ($action) {
    case 'todos':
        $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM todos order by id desc")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        echo json_encode($query);
        break;
}
```

Although I have the `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *')`, It throws me the MissingAllowOriginHeader error:

> Access to fetch at 'http://localhost/react-php-backend' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

What is the reason that gives this error? How can I fix this? Because of that I cannot connect database.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I am following a tutorial and this is how the lecturer done. It was working in the video. Codes are the same with the tutorial.

Comment: Then I suggest to ask your question of the person that posted the tutorial

Comment: I don't think @RiggsFolly is correct, this looks fine to me. Can you take a look at the HTTP response that's failing, and take a look at the response body and headers that are set there? Are you going to the correct endpoint?

Comment: Hopefully https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43262121/trying-to-use-fetch-and-pass-in-mode-no-cors/43268098#43268098 helps you.

Comment: Also connecting to database can be independently tested via the backend. Just test the backend api and see if the connects to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 2023, when almost all browsers requires strick origin policy you need to modify your headers, either in .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
   #Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
   SetEnvIf Origin "http(s)?://(.+\.)?domain\.ext(:\d{1,5})?$" CORS=$0
   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "%{CORS}e" env=CORS
   Header merge  Vary "Origin"
   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"
   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "*"
   
</IfModule>
```

or inside php

```
<?php
function cors()
{
    // for options, return imm.
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {
        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))
        // may also be using PUT, PATCH, HEAD etc
        {
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");
        }

        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS'])) {
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");
        }

        exit(0);
    }

    $origin = "*";
    if (isset($_REQUEST['origin'])) {
        $origin = $_REQUEST['origin'];
    }

    if (isset($_SERVER['origin'])) {
        $origin = $_SERVER['origin'];
    }

    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
        $origin = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
    }

    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
        $origin = $_SERVER["HTTP_ORIGIN"];
    }

    // remove trailing / for origin
    $origin = rtrim($origin, "/");

    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: " . $origin, true);
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *", true);
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS, post, get', true);
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true', true);
}

cors();
```

tbh, both would be also ok...