# JS API: Cant Post XML and get response body (CORS error)

Tags: javascript, xml, xmlhttprequest

I'm getting more and more frustrated...and maybe there are some points I recently don't understand.
But, first things first:
I made an html-vite app and run it locally. I made some api get-calls (JSON bodies) (js fetch..) to internal and external servers - everything ok!

Every Call is done in JS, get-call with fetch, the post with fetch or XMLHttpRequest (tried both!).

BUT when I try to make a post (with xml body!) to an external server I get CORS errors.

I'm not 100% sure if its really a CORS error, because other external APIs are working without any issues.

So this is the XMLHttpRequest:

```
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
  xhr.withCredentials = true;
  xhr.onload = success; 
  xhr.onerror = error; 

  xhr.open('POST', API_URL); 

  xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', '*/*');
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept-Language', 'en-GB');
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept-Encoding', 'gzip, deflate');
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Connection', 'Keep-alive');
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Length', 'xmlBody.length');
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  xhr.setRequestHeader('access-control-allow-methods', 'OPTIONS,GET,POST');

  xhr.setRequestHeader('Origin', 'http://localhost:5173/');
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Pragma', 'no-cache');
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');

  xhr.send(xmlBody); // xmlBody contains the xml in a one-line-string...
```

there is also an OPTION-Request which fails(403 - Forbidden)!

I`ve tried a lot :)
With JS-Fetch, with/without any headers in different combinations..
With mode:cors or mode:no-cors -> then the response is opaque. the reason is also clear for me...

**What I figured out:**
in other get-calls: if the body is not "correct", the error can be interpreted as an CORS error (the JSON-body was not correct..).
so its maybe the XML-Body? I put the xml without line-breaks in a string and set it to the body.
the content looks well, and with copy paste it works in postman, too!

in the Firefox dev-tools --> network --> I can see that the post has an error "**NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI**".
I can edit the request and re-send it with the xml body and get an **working response**!

Comment: Attaching the CORS headers *to the request* makes zero sense. CORS headers are specified *by the server* to say what sources are allowed or not. Having the client say "Hi, I'm allowed as a source" defeats the whole purpose of having this mechanism. Hence why it doesn't work. "*mode:no-cors -> then the response is opaque*" becase `no-cors` is exactly the opposite of what you want. It only really means "avoid CORS errors, as I am not going to read the response". [Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43268098).

Comment: "*I'm not 100% sure if its really a CORS error, because other external APIs are working without any issues.*" The way CORS works is that *a server* specifies which requests and origins are valid. And the browser enforces these restrictions. So naturally one origin might be allowed for server A but not for B. Therefore, being able to reach one API but not another is exactly how CORS should work. Read more here: [XMLHttpRequest cannot load XXX No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35553500)

Comment: thanks for your answers! The post is working in postman and in the firefox dev tools, but not in the js-environment... and that is confusing me. hmm.. the request from postman should have the origin from my pc, the request from firefox-dev-tools too, but the origin from the html is localhost:nnnn, which could be restricted from the "post"-server?

Comment: Only requests made inside browsers are bound by the CORS restrictions. Postman or other application won't be. A tool *might* choose to respect CORS but is in no way obliged to. Browsers guarantee it.

Comment: uff... what i forgot... to make things a bit more quirky: the site should be hosted on a webserver which is only accessible inside the company network. here is a proxy running.. but this info is nice to know with no effort, right? so the only thing i can do, is to have a look about jsonp ? and why are there cors-headers when they make no sense in requests? my brain hurts :)

Comment: You can proxy the request through some backend server. Those are also not bound by CORS policies, so you can make a request from the page (A) to your proxy (B) which makes a request to the actual target you want (C). You can set the CORS policy in your server so A -> B is accepted. Then B -> C would work since it won't be bound by CORS. Thus breaking the restrictions that A -> C would run into.