# JSON.parse() Vs. .json()

Tags: javascript, json, fetch-api

I have been working with fetch API and Promises recently and I came across .json() . Oftentimes .json() returns the same output as JSON.parse. I googled the question and the results pointed in other directions.

Example with XHR and JSON.parse:

```
$('#xhr').click(function(){
  var XHR = new XMLHttpRequest();

  XHR.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (XHR.status == 200 && XHR.readyState == 4) {
      $('#quote').text(JSON.parse(XHR.responseText)[0]);
    }
  };

  XHR.open("GET", url);
  XHR.send();
});
```

Example with Fetch API:

```
$('#fetch').click(function(){
  fetch(url)
  .then(function(res){
    return res.json();
  })
  .then(function(quote){
    $('#quote').text(quote);
  })
  .catch(function(err){
    handleError(err);
  });
});
```

Could someone please explain the difference between these seemingly similar concepts ?
Thanks

Comment: Could you show your codes?

Comment: @fool-dev had you read this question?

Comment: I added examples

Comment: Maybe duplicate of [What is the difference between the Fetch API and XMLHttpRequest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35549547/what-is-the-difference-between-the-fetch-api-and-xmlhttprequest) ?

Comment: @tsh How does the linked Question resolve the inquiry at the present Question?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

[`Body.json()`](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-body-json) is asynchronous and returns a `Promise` object that resolves to a JavaScript object. [`JSON.parse()`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-json.parse) is synchronous can parse a string and change the resulting returned JavaScript object.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. :)

Comment: Body.json() returns a promise - but i see some examples where data = Body.json() is used so the data is accessed directly- apparently without unwrapping the promise  - but in other examples i see the promise used via  .then(data) and the data is accessed off of the promise. Why does the first example work? Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

'AJAX' works with 'callbacks';
'fetch' works with 'promises'.

Use JSON.parse() to parse the response for AJAX.
Use json() to parse the response for fetch.

Answer (score 4):

The json() method of the Body mixin takes a **Response** stream and reads it to completion. It returns a promise that resolves with the result of parsing the body text as JSON.
The JSON.parse() method parses a **JSON string**, constructing the JavaScript value or object described by the string.

Use JSON.parse() to parse the response for AJAX. Use json() to parse the response for fetch.

Answer (score 3):

In my view both res.json and JSON.parse do the same functioning. Preference to res.json is given because of it's syntax.
Sharing the example for better understanding...

```
 this.service.userFunction() //calling service
.then((res) => {
 this.userdetails = JSON.parse(res._body); //use this
 this.userdetails = res.json(); // or use this syntax any one
 )}
.catch()
```

Using any of one them will provide the the complete response body and understanding of their functionality.

Comment: res.json() returns a promise, so after returning that, you would need to chain an additional then(data){ this.userdetails = data }