# Accessing promise data from Node API inside React fetch call

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, express

I'm putting together a React app that consumes data from a Node/Express REST API which is currently on my local machine. I've got a simple `res.json` returning a Sequelize object, and I'm accessing it through a service I made. Obviously, I'm going to be putting the object in `state` eventually, but I'm currently having difficulty accessing the values.

```
const options = {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({email: "matthewharp@gmail.com", password: "M1nerals"})
};
fetch('http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in', options)
    .then(response => console.log(response.json()));
```

I'm getting the results in the console, but they're stuck in the [[PromiseValue]].

[image]

I must be missing some kind of async step, but I'm not sure what.

Comment: `fetch('http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in', options).then(response => response.json()).then(data => console.log(data));`

Comment: Related: [JSON.parse() Vs. .json()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48295439/691711)

Answer (score 0):

The `json` method returns a promise, which you *also* need to await. So do:

```
fetch('http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in', options)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(obj => console.log(obj));
```

Answer (score 0):

You're having this error because `response.json()` return a promise.

you need to do 
`fetch('http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in', options)
 .then(response => response.json())
 .then(res => console.log(res));`

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the promise from the fetch call or else you need to act on it in the then for the json promise.

```
const options = {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({email: "matthewharp@gmail.com", password: "M1nerals"})
};
return fetch('http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in', options)
    .then(response => {
         console.log(response.json())
         return response.json()
    }
);
```

or...

```
const options = {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({email: "matthewharp@gmail.com", password: "M1nerals"})
    };
   fetch('http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in', options)
        .then(response => {
             console.log(response.json())
            response.json().then( result => {
               // whatever you're doing with the data here.
        }
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `fetch` api:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

You need a separate `then` chained to take the json data once ready, and it will give you the values.

```
('http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in', options)
.then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
})
.then(function(myJson) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(myJson));
});
```