# Why don't apollo-client's GraphQL queries appear in Chrome's XHR Network filter?

Tags: xmlhttprequest, google-chrome-devtools, apollo-client

I'm using apollo-client, and I've just noticed that my GraphQL queries don't appear on the list of Network calls when the XHR filter is active.

How is this possible? GQL is just a set of semantics on top of regular old HTTP, right? It's not like a JS library can introduce a whole new networking capability.

In the first image below, you see me filtering for requests with "gra" in them; two appear: the OPTIONS call, and then the POST (which is the real meat). In the second image, I additionally filter by XHRs; the POST is gone.

[image]

The "XHR" filter says it captures "XHR and Fetch". The only alternative I can think of would be dynamically adding `<script>` tags to the document, and I very much doubt that's how apollo-client is managing things.

I don't know what the "json" Type is. The [docs for the DevTools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/reference#filter-by-type) don't mention that type.

Comment: I'd like to know it too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the reason for this is that Chrome's `fetch` capability is not simply sugar on top of the age-old `XMLHttpRequest` capability, and the filter option in the DevTools (which says "XHR") is either not built or not designed as an umbrella "asynchronous request" filter. I hope they change that, especially since the Type column in the Network panel can still be used to differentiate between the two.

If I had to speculate, I'd say the behavior we observe flows from the way the Network tab hooks into the underlying networking code, and `fetch` calls don't travel the relevant portion of the codepath that XHR does. As supporting evidence, I offer [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40877968/814463), which highlights functional differences between XHR & `fetch` that might readily be explained by their being entirely separate code. (It's also possible some of these differences are a result of the `fetch` spec explicitly calling for behavior different from XHR.)

Finally, I'd add that we probably only noticed this with Apollo's GQL tools because apollo-client was created in a post-XHR world, and may be one of the first libraries we worked with that prefers `fetch` over XHR rather than using an XHR polyfill.