# What's the best way to check the connectivity in pure JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, fetch

I've a tried a lot of things to check the internet connection of the users of my app. My first researches brought me to the `navigator.onLine` method. It works sometimes. But sometimes it doesn't. Of course it's not new, I have seen multiples people complaining about that.

Then I tried the XHR request. It was working on every devices, whatever the internet navigator (not like the previous method). But I got some warnings from Chrome and Firefox cos it was synchronous and may slow the whole app.

So I converted my function to an asynchronous function :

```
function verification() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", "//" + window.location.hostname + "/ressources/favicon.ico?rand=" + Date.now(), true);

    xhr.onload = function (e) {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
            reconnection();
        }
    };

    xhr.onerror = function (e) {
        deconnexion();
    };

    xhr.send(null);
}
```

The idea is simple, I check if I can access to the favicon (with a rand to make it unique and avoid cache ressource). If the request is a success then I consider I'm connected. If not, I'm not connected. So far, it seems to work pretty well.

My question is : is it the best way to do that with pure JS ? Or should I maybe consider using `fetch` ? Or is there a better way I didn't find ?

Comment: `fetch` is not pure JS?

Comment: The [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) method returns a `Promise` and is completely `async`.

Comment: I didn't mean that `fetch`is not pure JS. I just wonder what's the best method for what I want to do

Comment: If it works like this, then go with it. It's not necessarily better or worst than the `fetch` API. (You can see the differences [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35549547/fetch-api-vs-xmlhttprequest).) Personally I would use an endpoint that returns a [`204`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/204) with a [`Cache-Control: no-store`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control) response header. That way you don't need to load an image for every request.