# XMLHttpRequest, AJAX, JSP, Load data into form

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, jsp, xmlhttprequest

If the object contains more fields than what are referenced in the form, then it breaks, how can I prevent this (https://jsfiddle.net/a4v7p2xg/2/) the snippet below works.

```js
var data = {
  "firstname": "David",
  "lastname": "Garcia"
};

$( document ).ready(function() {
Object.keys(data).forEach(key => document.querySelector(`input[data-name="${key}"]`).value = data[key]);
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- JS -->

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
      body {
        font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
        color: #333333
      }

    </style>
  </head>


  <body style="" class="">
    <div class="container px-4">
      <div class="row gx-5 align-items-center">
        <div class="col-2 p-1">First Name</div>
        <div class="col p-1"><input name="firstname" data-name="firstname" class="form-control" id="firstname" type="text" /></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row gx-5 align-items-center">
        <div class="col-2 p-1">Last Name</div>
        <div class="col p-1"><input name="lastname" data-name="lastname" class="form-control" id="lastname" type="text" /></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First off, instead of using `XMLHTTPRequest`, you should be using the `fetch` api, built-in to JS. [See this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35549547/fetch-api-vs-xmlhttprequest)
- Secondly, you can set the `value` of the inputs after adding `data-name` attributes to each `input` which corresponds to the key of the value of the object you want to set its value to . Here's how I would do that:

```
function addToForm(data){
    Object.keys(data).forEach(key => document.querySelector(`[data-name="${key}"]`) == null ? 0 : document.querySelector(`[data-name="${key}"]`).value = data[key])
}
```

Comment: Like this? `success: function(response) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(response));
        addToForm(response)
    }`

Comment: Yes! but after adding the appropriate attributes to the inputs.

Comment: Hey Never, when there are more keys in the object than what are referenced in the form, then it breaks, how can It be prevented. https://jsfiddle.net/a4v7p2xg/2/

Comment: Oops! didn't think of that edge-case, fixed it though.