# abort fetch when component unmount

Tags: react-native

how could I cancel fetch operation when component go away (unmount)

**example** :  user open this screen and go back before fetch complete

here is what I have done

```
export default class LecturesScreen extends React.Component
{
      constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {lectures : [] , loadingNow : true}
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.loadLectures();
    }

    loadLectures = () =>{
        fetch(Link.api.lecture.newest , {method : 'POST'})
            .then((response) =>
            {
                this.setState({lectures : response , loadingNow: false});
            })
            .catch((error)=>
            {
                console.log(error);
            });
    };

    render(){
        return (
            <View>

                <List dataArray={this.state.lectures}
                      renderRow={(item) => <LectureListItem title={item.Title}/>}
                />

            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Edit:

I don't think it's currently possible to cancel/abort a fetch request.
You can follow the discussion here:

https://github.com/whatwg/fetch/issues/447

Call a function on componentDidUnmount like mentioned below.

```
componentWillUnmount(){
    this.unLoadLectures();
}

unLoadLectures = () =>{
   this.state = {lectures : [] , loadingNow : true}
};
```

Comment: I think that will not abort `fetch` function

Comment: Take a look at this post.
https://discuss.reactjs.org/t/cancel-async-fetch-on-unmount/3272

Comment: also this post.
I don't think it's possible.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31061838/how-do-i-cancel-an-http-fetch-request

https://github.com/whatwg/fetch/issues/447

Comment: If you find this helpful, kindly upvote or accept the answer. Thanks.