# How is it possible to cancel network requests?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, networking, fetch

js][1](https://github.com/facebook/react) say that it is possible to *cancel networkrequest* (this is about `componentWillUnmount()` method):

> Perform any necessary cleanup in this method, such as invalidating timers, **canceling network requests**, ...

But [answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31061838/how-do-i-cancel-an-http-fetch-request) say it is not possible.

Question being, is it possible or not to cancel a network requests in JS?

For example. I started `setInterval` with requests using `fetch` API in `componentDidMount`. On some condition I want to stop requests. I want to do so in `componentWilUnmount`. So how can I cancel all network requests?
I'm not talking about calling `clearInterval` which will stop `setInterval`. I want to make sure that any network requests that were started will be canceled in a given condition.

Answer (score 0):

Generally this is not always possible. However XHR object has an `abort` method or `axios` library has this ability, but basically it will drop the query but the connection remains.