# How to cancel network requests in JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

[The React documentation for `componentWillUnmount()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillunmount) implies that it is possible to *cancel network requests*:

> Perform any necessary cleanup in this method, such as invalidating timers, **canceling network requests**, ...

But [answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31061838/how-do-i-cancel-an-http-fetch-request) say it is not possible.

Question being, is it possible or not to cancel a network requests in JS?

For example, if I started a `setInterval` to requests using the Fetch API in `componentDidMount`, and on some condition I want to stop requests, doing so in `componentWillUnmount` per the documentation. How can I cancel all network requests? I'm not talking about calling `clearInterval`, which will stop the timer. I want to make sure that any network requests that were started will be canceled in a given condition.

Comment: Read the second answer to the question you linked. "Network requests" doesn’t have to mean Fetch, either; XHR has [`.abort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/abort).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31061838/how-do-i-cancel-an-http-fetch-request

Comment: @epascarello that's the "answers here" link

Comment: [window.stop()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/stop)

Comment: Well that link says it is possible in browsers that support. Look at the second answer.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this is just an experimental API.
Therefore, yes it is possible, but no not in all browsers.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController/abort

EDIT

For plain AJAX request it is definitely possible:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/abort