# Multiple fetch() with one signal in order to abort them all

Tags: javascript, fetch-api, abort

I saw this other answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47250621/2809729

So can I abort multiple fetch request using just one signal?

Answer (score 5):

At the time I was writing the question, I already found the solution in [this post on how to abort fetches](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/abortable-fetch) from one of the pioneers that were working to the implementation of an abort.

So yes you can :)
Here a brief example:

```
async function fetchStory({ signal }={}) {
  const storyResponse = await fetch('/story.json', { signal });
  const data = await storyResponse.json();

  const chapterFetches = data.chapterUrls.map(async url => {
    const response = await fetch(url, { signal });
    return response.text();
  });

  return Promise.all(chapterFetches);
}
```

In the above example, the same signal is used for the initial fetch, and for the parallel chapter fetches. Here's how you'd use fetchStory:

```
const controller = new AbortController();
const signal = controller.signal;

fetchStory({ signal }).then(chapters => {
  console.log(chapters);
});
```

In this case, calling controller.abort() will reject the promise of the in-progress fetches.

Answer (score 1):

I abstracted the solution to this problem, and came up with "fetch-tx", fetch transaction, which provides a single abort function to all related fetch operations.

you can find it here:
[fetch-tx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fetch-tx)

Comment: oh well, actually I ended up creating my own fetch wrapper that lets you abort all of them or singularly each one of them https://giacomocerquone.com/blog/fetch-wrapper

@OrBachar