# How does the browser signal cancellation to the server?

Tags: asp.net-core

In ASP .NET Core, I can inject a `CancellationToken` into my actions which will signal cancellation when the HTTP request is cancelled by the browser.

I'm thinking this is detected from the server side by detecting if the underlying TCP connection is closed, but I haven't been able to find anything regarding this anywhere.

Does the browser somehow send a message to the server that indicates cancellation?

Comment: Well, since HTTP itself is not bidirectional and while the server computes the request, there is no way to cancel it (without making second - and quite convoluted - request), which is not made, then all is left is TCP connection close, which is easily detected by the server.

Comment: There are some "Abort Stream" hints [here (kestrel server)](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Servers/Kestrel/Core/src/Internal/Http2/Http2Stream.cs)., may be it is what you're looking for. If not, try some other files.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31061838/how-do-i-cancel-an-http-fetch-request

Comment: https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/http-the-definitive/1565925092/ch04s07.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The cancellation token is triggered when the connection is closed. The browser doesn't communicate anything. It's the action of the user browsing away, closing the tab/window, etc.: situations where the browser responds by closing the connection to the server.

Comment: And what do you think of AbortController? Does that send a request then? And is it supported by ASP .NET Core? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController

Comment: That's entirely a JS thing. It has no relationship to anything going on in ASP.NET Core. *If* aborting causes the underlying connection to be closed, then it should also trigger cancellation server-side, but it's not clear from the spec that it does.