# How to set a time limit to a method in NodeJs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, synchronous

I have a use case, where I am doing an external API call from my code,
The response of the external API is required by my code further on
I am bumping into a scenario, where the external API call at times takes far too long to return a response,
casing my code to break, being a serverless function

So I want to set a time limit to the external API call,
Where if I don't get any response from it within 3 secs, I wish the code to gracefully stop the further process

Following is a pseudo-code of what I am trying to do, but couldn't figure out the logic -

```
let test = async () => {
    let externalCallResponse = '';

    await setTimeout(function(){ 

        //this call sometimes takes for ever to respond, but I want to limit just 3secs to it
        externalCallResponse = await externalCall();
    }, 3000);

    if(externalCallResponse != ''){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}

test();
```

**Reference -**
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SSM.html#getParameters-property
I'm using AWS SSM's getParameters method

Comment: What library are you using for queries? Almost every one of them has a parameter `timeout`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I cancel an HTTP fetch() request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31061838/how-do-i-cancel-an-http-fetch-request)

Comment: @NikitaMadeev I'm using an AWS service SSM's getParameters, which is timing out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot await `setTimeout` as it doesn't returns a `Promise`.

You could implement a function that returns a `Promise` which is fulfilled after 3 seconds.

```
function timeout(seconds) {
   return new Promise((resolve) => {
       setTimeout(resolve, seconds * 1000)
   });
}
```

You can await the above function in your code passing the number of seconds you want to wait for

```
let test = async () => {
    let externalCallResponse = ''; 
    
    setTimeout(async () => {
       externalCallResponse = await externalCall();
    }, 0);

    await timeout(3); // wait for 3 seconds 

    if(externalCallResponse != '') return true;
    else return false;
}
```

Following code snippet demonstrates the usage of `timeout` function written above. It mocks a api request that returns a response after 4 seconds.

```js
function timeout(seconds) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(resolve, seconds * 1000);
  });
}

function apiRequest() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve('Hello World'), 4000);
  });
}

let test = async () => {
  let externalCallResponse = '';

  setTimeout(async () => {
    externalCallResponse = await apiRequest();
  }, 0);

  await timeout(3); // wait for 3 seconds

  if (externalCallResponse != '') return true;
  else return false;
};

test()
  .then(res => console.log(res))
  .catch(err => console.log(err.message));
```

Comment: What is the idea behind wrapping `externalCallResponse = await apiRequest();` with setTimeout of 0 secs?

Comment: zero is the default delay so you can omit passing zero as a second argument. If you want to schedule the callback function to run after specific number of milliseconds, you can change zero to any number you want.

Comment: so the wrapper is like required for the timeout logic? `setTimeout(async () => {
    externalCallResponse = await apiRequest();
  }, 0);`, I can't just do `externalCallResponse = await apiRequest();` right? Wanted to understand why that wrapping is required?

Comment: if you just do `externalCallResponse = await apiRequest();` then `await timeout(3);` will not be executed until API response comes back. Wrapping API request in `setTimeout` helps us schedule the code that makes API request to run after executing `await timeout(3);`. Basically, we want to start our timeout timer before we actually make the request.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
const timeout = async (func, millis) => {
   return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => reject(), millis);

      resolve(await func());
   });
}

timeout(() => doStuff(), 3000)
   .then(() => console.log('worked'))
   .catch(() => console.log('timed out'));
```

Tests:

```js
const timeout = async (func, millis) => {
   return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => reject(), millis);

      resolve(await func());
   });
}

const doStuffShort = async () => { // Runs for 1 second
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve(), 1000));
}

const doStuffLong = async () => { // Runs for 5 seconds
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve(), 5000));
}

timeout(() => doStuffShort(), 3000)
   .then(() => console.log('1 worked'))
   .catch(() => console.log('1 timed out'));
   

timeout(() => doStuffLong(), 3000)
   .then(() => console.log('2 worked'))
   .catch(() => console.log('2 timed out'));
```

Comment: Using promises inside `Promise` constructor is an [anti pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43036229/is-it-an-anti-pattern-to-use-async-await-inside-of-a-new-promise-constructor)

Comment: Thanks for the hint @Yousaf One could potentially rewrite it to just work with `.then()` inside the Promise and resolve from there, but I have no time right now. Good catch though

Answer (score 1):

you can use something like this, I created a function that return a promise then I used this promise.

```js
let test = async () => {

    return promiseTimeout()
}

const promiseTimeout = () => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(function () {
            let externalCallResponse=""
            externalCallResponse = await externalCall();
            if (externalCallResponse != '') {
                return resolve(true);
            }
            else {
                return resolve(false);
            }
        }, 3000);
    })
}

test().then(result=>{
    console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: Using promises inside `Promise` constructor is an [anti pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43036229/is-it-an-anti-pattern-to-use-async-await-inside-of-a-new-promise-constructor)