# How to cancel async Task from the client

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, cancellationtokensource, cancellation-token

I have on ASP.Net C# web API with an endpoint for the import. Javascript client sends a list of items to this API and API process this list in another thread (long task) and immediately returns unique id (GUID) of process. Now I need the cancel the background task from the **CLIENT**. Is possible to somehow send the cancelation token from the client? I have tried to add CancellationToken as a parameter to my controller async action but I don't know how to pass it from the client. For simplification, we can use as the client the Postman app.

**Sample server-side**

```
    [HttpPost]
    [UserContextActionFilter]
    [RequestBodyType(typeof(List<List<Item>>))]
    [Route("api/bulk/ImportAsync")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> ImportAsync()
    {
        var body = await RequestHelper.GetRequestBody(this);
        var queue = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<List<Item>>>(body);
        var resultWrapper = new AsynckResultWrapper(queue.Count);


        HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(async ct =>
        {
            foreach (var item in queue)
            {
                var result = await ProcessItemList(item, false);
                resultWrapper.AddResultItem(result);
            }
        });

        return Ok(new
        {
            ProcessId = resultWrapper.ProcessId.ToString()
        });
    }


    private async Task<ItemResult> ProcessItemList(<List<Item>>itemList, bool runInOneTransaction = false)
    {
        try
        {
            var result = await PerformBulkOperation(true, itemList);
            return new ResultWrapper(result);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            // process exception
            return new ResultWrapper(ex);

        }
    }
```

Comment: please read: [How do I cancel an HTTP fetch() request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31061838/how-do-i-cancel-an-http-fetch-request) and [Using CancellationTokens in ASP.NET Core MVC controllers](https://andrewlock.net/using-cancellationtokens-in-asp-net-core-mvc-controllers/)

Comment: So to be clear, you want to cancel the work that is queued on the  background worker?

Comment: @PeterBons yes, i want to cancel the task on the background worker. Is there any way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On a high level what you could do is store the process id along with a cancellation token source when you queue the work. Then you can expose a new endpoint that accepts a process id, gets the cancellation token source from the store and cancels the associated token:

```cs
        [HttpPost]
        [UserContextActionFilter]
        [RequestBodyType(typeof(List<List<Item>>))]
        [Route("api/bulk/ImportAsync")]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> ImportAsync()
        {
            var body = await RequestHelper.GetRequestBody(this);
            var queue = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<List<Item>>>(body);
            var resultWrapper = new AsynckResultWrapper(queue.Count);

            HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(async ct =>
            {
                var lts = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(ct);
                var ct = lts.Token;
                TokenStore.Store(resultWrapper.ProcessId, lts);

                foreach (var item in queue)
                {
                    var result = await ProcessItemList(item, ct, false);
                    resultWrapper.AddResultItem(result);
                }

                TokenStore.Remove(processId) // remove the cancellation token source from storage when doen, because there is nothing to cancel
            });

            return Ok(new
            {
                ProcessId = resultWrapper.ProcessId.ToString()
            });
        }


        private async Task<ItemResult> ProcessItemList(<List<Item>>itemList, CancellationToken token, bool runInOneTransaction = false)
        {
            try
            {
                var result = await PerformBulkOperation(true, itemList, token);
                return new ResultWrapper(result);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                // process exception
                return new ResultWrapper(ex);

            }
        }

        [Route("api/bulk/CancelImportAsync")]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> CancelImportAsync(Guid processId)
        {
            var tokenSource = TokenStore.Get(processId);
            tokenSource.Cancel();

            TokenStore.Remove(processId) // remove the cancellation token source from storage when cancelled
        }
```

In the above example I modified the `ProcessItemList` to accept a cancellation token and pass it to `PerformBulkOperation`, assuming that method has support for cancellation tokens. If not, you can manually call `ThrowIfCancellationRequested();` on the cancellation token at certain points in the code to stop when cancellation is requested.

I've added a new endpoint that allows you to cancel a pending operation.

**Disclaimer**
There are for sure some things you need to think about, especially when it is a public api. You can extend the store to accepts some kind of security token and when cancellation is requested you check whether it matches with the security token that queued the work. My answer is focused on the basics of the question

Also, I left the implementation of the store to your own imagination ;-)

Comment: I cannot tell whether it is safe solution - i.e. can the process be stopped by an arbitrary client? I.e. client A invokes import action, thhen some random client (other rom A) invokes CancelImportAsync? This way, client A will never get his results, even though he didn't cancell import.

Comment: @MichałTurczyn Yeah , there are for sure some things you need to think about, especially when it is a public api. You can extend the store to accepts some kind of security token and when cancellation is requested you check whether it matches with the security token that queued the work. My answer is focused on the basics of the question.

Comment: @MichałTurczyn It is not the responsibility of a Stack Overflow answer to provide a full solution that takes into account every possible permutation. It is the responsibility of the person using the answer to **use their brain** and alter the answer to fit their specific scenario. If they don't do that, it is their fault when problems crop up.

Comment: @PeterBons Thanks a lot. This is what I need.

Comment: How to store cancellation token source and retrieve it from another api call?

Comment: @RDeveloper You could use a `Dictionary<string, CancellationTokenSource>` for example.

Comment: How this will work with 2 APIs? First API run QueueBackgroundWorkItem long running task. And then if client want to cancel long running task how this can be done with second api call? In second api call how do we access the dictionary?

Comment: The first api could return a id, that id is used as the key in the dictionary along with the CancellationTokenSource, then the second api takes that id and uses it to cancel to corresponding work.

Comment: I get that using a id as key for dictionary but where dictionary will be stored. In the second api call Dictionary will be still in memory?

Comment: I would wrap it in a class and register it as a singleton so it stays in memory and can be accessed by different endpoints