# Fetch API : is it possible to request partial html page (the beginning)

Tags: javascript

I can request an html page with Fetch API, but I just need the title, is it possible to request partial html page (the beginning) ?

Comment: You could consume the fetched html as a stream and abort the fetch once you have what you need.

Comment: Isn't it better using DOMParser?

Comment: DOMParser is AFTER so too late ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The title of a page exists in the HTML markup. For this page, it's:

```
<head>
  <title>javascript - Fetch API : is it possible to request partial html page (the beginning) - Stack Overflow</title>
```

So you will need to at least make an initial request for the *whole* page response.

If you want to try to stop parsing the response as soon as the first chunk (which will likely contain the `<title>`) comes in, you could use a [readable stream](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Streams_API/Using_readable_streams) and [close](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStreamDefaultController/close) and/or use an [`AbortController`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31061838/how-do-i-cancel-an-http-fetch-request).