# How do I do a HEAD operation on an AWS Presigned URL?

Tags: java, amazon-s3, file-transfer

I am trying to get the size of an obejct in S3.  I know I can do it via `GET` but I want to use the `HEAD` method.  But I can't find in the AWS SDK `HeadObjectPresignRequest` only `GetObjectPresignRequest`.  Using `HEAD` on the presigned URL gives me a 403

Right now what I am doing is [Cancelling the fetch request](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47250621/242042)

Answer (score 3):

We need to pass `headObject` to getSignedUrl method itself.

JavaScript:

```
s3.getSignedUrl(
  "headObject",
  {
    Bucket: "my-test-bucket",
    Key: "path/to/my/object",
  },
  (error, url) => {
    if (error) console.log("error", error);
    if (url) console.log("url", url);
  }
);
```

Java:

```
AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withRegion("us-east-1").build();       
URL url = s3Client.generatePresignedUrl(new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest("my-test-bucket", "path/to/my/object",HttpMethod.HEAD));
System.out.println(url.toString());
```

Then HEAD request on the object.

```
curl --location --head 'https://my-test-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/myobject?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=ASIA....Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20210418T230000Z&X-Amz-Expires=900&X-Amz-Security-Token=....%2B31dbfIXMQ%3D%3D&X-Amz-Signature=...ad&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host'
```

Comment: thx I realized I missed the java tag.  I needed this in Java SDK.

Comment: @ArchimedesTrajano Updated with java example

Comment: Thanks. it appears GeneratePresignedUrlRequest is on SDK 1 but not on SDK2