# Async operation in queue javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, async-await

I am working with react functional component.

I have download(async) functionality in my application. There is list of download buttons in my app. I want to download them one by one in queue.

```
const [downloadQueue, setDownloadQueue] = useState([]);

onClickDonwload = () => { //on every download click this function calls. So user can click on download continuously but I want to make sure them to be downloaded one by one.
  downloadQueue([...downloadQueue, { id, data }])
}

useEffect(() => {
  downloadQueue.map(async(data) => {
    await myDownloadAsyncFunction()
  })
}, [downloadQueue])  // here the issue is whenever the downloadQueue updates it just start downloading without waiting for the previous one
```

Kindly help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I cancel an HTTP fetch() request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31061838/how-do-i-cancel-an-http-fetch-request)

Comment: @AshishChoudary What does `myDownloadAsyncFunction` do - can you edit the question to include more detail on it? For example, include a simplified version of its code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this? It uses Promise-chaining to make a simple queue

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

// Any async function or function that returns a promise
async function myDownloadAsyncFunction(data) {
  return fetch('https://mydomain.test/path');
}

function DownloadButton() {
  const [queue, setQueue] = useState(Promise.resolve());

  onClickDownload = () => {
    setQueue(queue
      .then(() => myDownloadAsyncFunction('My data'))
      .catch((err) => {console.error(err)})
    )
  }

  return (
    <button onClick={onClickDownload}>Download</button>
  );
}
```

The above doesn't trigger the download from `useEffect`. If you do want to use `useEffect`, I think the state would probably need to be a counter to cause `useEffect` to run when it changes:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";

// Any async function or function that returns a promise
async function myDownloadAsyncFunction(data) {
  return fetch('https://mydomain.test/path');
}

function DownloadButton() {
  const queue = useRef(Promise.resolve());
  const [clickCount, setClickCount] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (clickCount == 0) return;
    queue.current = queue.current
      .then(() => myDownloadAsyncFunction('My data'))
      .catch((err) => {console.error(err)});
  }, [clickCount]);

  function onClickDownload() {
    setClickCount(clickCount + 1);
  }

  return (
    <button onClick={onClickDownload}>Download</button>
  );
}
```

Note in both of the above examples might need to get more complicated to better deal with some of the downloads failing. In these examples though, if a download fails, the next one should continue to attempt to be downloaded.

Comment: If I want to pass data in `myDownloadAsyncFunction` I can do like this `setDownloadQueue(downloadQueue.finally(myDownloadAsyncFunction(data)))
` right?

Comment: @AshishChoudary No, you'll need to use `downloadQueue.finally(() => myDownloadAsyncFunction(data)))`

Comment: @AshishChoudary Ah not quite - I've edited the examples to show how you would do that

Comment: Using `.finally()` will cause an unhandled promise rejection on every download after a single one has failed once. Better add `.catch()` on every call

Comment: @Bergi Thanks! I didn't realise that's what happened without a ".catch()"

Comment: @Bergi Although I am just testing that and I don't think the catch is needed... perhaps with `then` it would be, but `finally` runs in the case of both failed and success. In fact, I thought that was the main purpose of `finally`?

Comment: @Bergi Ah I might have just misunderstood what you meant... but from testing, I think that with `finally` and no `catch`, then there is still only a single unhandled promise rejection in the console

Comment: Hm, there's only one unhandled promise rejection at a time, but it's a new one with every step; firing an `unhandledrejection` event for the new promsie  and a `rejectionhandled` event for the previous promise. How that is displayed in the devtools seems to differ.

Comment: Ah ok. In any case, opted to now use `then` + `catch` to avoid the whole thing, as well as showing where some more complex error handling could go.

Comment: Exactly, the `queue = queue.then(runStep).catch(console.error)` is what I recommend

Comment: @Bergi & Michal... No this will not download in series. This will just download whichever would be done first(which I don't want) in the promise. I want them to be downloaded one after another. Suppose I click on the download button three times so I want first download to be completed first then second and then third.

Comment: @AshishChoudary From my testing of the "fake" download function, no matter how fast I repeatedly click the download button, there is 1 second interval between output to the console, so I think it should do it in series. Note - if you're using the `fetch` API, you have to make sure `return fetch(...` from the `myDownloadAsyncFunction` function

Comment: Yes that's what I am saying... You have used `1000` in setInterval that is why it will run it in series but in my case that's api call so we do not know which `download` click will take how much time. Isn't it?

Comment: @AshishChoudary Ah the `1000` here is just to emulate a request takes 1000ms so the example works without talking to another server. In the real case, the `myDownloadAsyncFunction` function can be `return fetch('https://domain.test/path')`, and it won't depend on how long it takes.

Comment: @AshishChoudary I've removed anything to do with the `1000`/fake download from the example now since I think it confused matters.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is :

```
const [downloading,setDownloading] = useState(false)

useEffect( ()=> {
  if(downloadQueue.length && !downloading){
    myDownloadAsyncFunction(downloadQueue[0].data).then(()=>{
      setDownloading(false)
      setDownLoadQueue((a) => a.slice(1))
    })
  }
},[downloadQueue])
```

From your code, I'm not sure how do you pass parameter to `myDownloadAsyncFunction()`. Here I juse assume that it use `downloadQueue[0].data`.

Comment: This will download the same thing multiple times

Comment: @Bergi Do you have any solution? kindly suggest

Comment: @Bergi, Yes, you are right. I forgot to add a downloading state. Have updated my answer and it should works now