# How to clear previous api call? (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, async-await

I'm trying to find a proper way to **"clear"** my first fetch request if a second one is made.

I have this:

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);

const callAPI = async () => {
    const api = await fetch(
      `my API`
    );
    const data = await api.json();
    setData(data);
```

The user can call the same api again to request similar or different date for a second, third, fourth time.... and I'm having issues with rendering information after the first call.
I receive the info from the fetch request but React won't load the info properly or at all.
I'm wondering if there is a proper way to do something like this:

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);

const callAPI = async () => {
 **  clearFetch() **
    const api = await fetch(
      `my API`
    );
    const data = await api.json();
    setData(data);
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is.  The `fetch()` function can be canceled.  You use an `AbortController`'s `signal` object.  The details can be seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31061838/how-do-i-cancel-an-http-fetch-request).

I will assume you have your call to `fetch()` inside a `useEffect()`.

```js
let abortC = null;
export default MyComponent = () => {
    useEffect(() => {
        abortC?.abort();
        abortC = new AbortController();
        var x = async () => {
            try {
                var response = await fetch('blah', { signal: abortC.signal });
                setSomeState(await response.json());
            }
            catch (ex) {
                // Whatever.
            }
        };
        x();
    }, [dependencies]);
    return ...
}
```

**UPDATE**:  Edited to take the declaration of `abortC` out to the top level so it is properly enclosed.  This would be in response of @EndlessCodebase's comment.  Many thanks for the observation.

Comment: Wouldn't `abortC` always be null because once you call `setSomeState()` the component re renders rendering a new null `abortC`. So you could never actually abort the fetch request because you would always be calling abort on a null AbortController. I think you would have to put the AbortController in a ref.

Answer (score 2):

you can use useEffect's [cleanup function](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#example-using-hooks-1) to clear previous call. In below code snippet api call will be ignored if `add-dependency-which-causes-to-rerun` changes within 500ms. Hope it helps!

```
useEffect(() => {
    const getData = setTimeout(async () => {
      const api = await fetch(
        'my API'
      );
      const data = await api.json();
      setData(data);

    },500)
    return () => clearTimeout(getData)
    
  }, [<add-dependency-which-causes-to-rerun>])
```

Comment: Thanks @Shoaibah, can you help me understand the idea a bit more?
The code I post (callApi) is triggered by a button in my app once the user enters an input. I'm assuming I can add the onPress function I have in my button where the [<add-dependency-which-causes-to-rerun>]  or should I use the onpress function to first trigger a clearTimeout(getData) then callApi? thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

if we are fetching data only on button click then above solution may NOT be a good option. I think you need something like this.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from 'react';

const FetchDetails = () => {
  const [inputIsChanged, setTnputIsChanged] = useState(false);
  const [prevInput, setPrevInput] = useState('');
  const inputRef = useRef('');
  const initialRender = useRef(true);

  const clickHander = () => {
    const currentValue = inputRef.current.value;

    setTnputIsChanged(inputRef.current.value !== prevInput);
    setPrevInput((prevState) =>
      prevState === currentValue ? prevState : currentValue
    );
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      if (initialRender.current || !inputIsChanged) {
        initialRender.current = false;
        return;
      }

      const response = await fetch(
        'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1'
      );
      const data = await response.json();
      console.log(data);
    })();
  }, [inputIsChanged]);

  return (
    <>
      <input type="text" ref={inputRef} />
      <button onClick={clickHander}>Fetch Details</button>
    </>
  );
};

export default FetchDetails;
```