# Form not submitting (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to have my console print `new blog added` when I add a new blog. But it's printing `fetch aborted`. I don't understand why it's failing to submit my form when I try to create one.
`Create.js`

```
import { useState } from "react";

const Create = () => {
   const [title, setTitle] = useState('');
   const [body, setBody] = useState('');
   const [author, setAuthor] = useState('');
   const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
   const handleSubmit = (e) => {
     e.preventDefault();
     const blog = { title, body, author };
     setIsLoading(true);

      fetch("http://localhost:8000/blogs", {
       method: "POST",
       headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
       body: JSON.stringify(blog),
      }).then(() => {
      console.log("new blog added");
       setIsLoading(false);
      })
   }

return (
  <div className="create">
    <h2>Add a new blog</h2>

    <form onSubmit={ handleSubmit } >
      <label>Blog title</label>
      <input type="text" required value={ title } onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)} />
      <label>Blog body</label>
      <textarea required value={ body } onChange={(e) => setBody(e.target.value)}></textarea>
      <label>Blog author</label>
    <select value={author} onChange={(e) => setAuthor(e.target.value)}>
      <option value="mario">Mario</option>
      <option value="yoshi">Yoshi</option>
    </select>
    </form>

    { !isLoading && <button>Add blog</button> }
    { isLoading && <button disabled>Adding blog...</button> }
    <p>{ title }</p>
    <p>{ body }</p>
    <p>{ author }</p>
  </div>
   );
}
 
export default Create;
```

`useFetch.js`

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const useFetch = (url) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const abortCont = new AbortController();

    fetch(url, { signal: abortCont.signal }).then(res => {
     if (!res.ok) {
       throw Error("Problem fetching data.");
     }
    return res.json();
    })
    .then((data) => {
      setData(data);
      setIsLoading(false);
      setError(null);
    }).catch((err) => {
      if (err.name === "AbortError") {
        console.log("fetch aborted");
      } else {
      setIsLoading(false);
      setError(err.message);
      }
    })
    return () => abortCont.abort();
  }, [url]);

return { data, isLoading, error }
}

export default useFetch;
```

Comment: You just stop aborting the request ?! -> "signal: abortCont.signal"
Check the accepted Answer, it may help in understanding: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31061838/how-do-i-cancel-an-http-fetch-request

Comment: You posted a custom `useFetch` hook but you aren't actually using it, you are using the raw fetch API in the other code you posted, so which is it? The first block of code you posted will not give that error. Please make sure to double-check your code before posting. Google search 10 times. Clean up/debug your code 5 times. Re-work your code 3 times. Post a question *once*.

Comment: @JaredSmith The other code I posted had an error which I was helped with, I needed fresh eyes it's now gone. What do you mean I'm not using my `useFetch` hook explain?. I have googled that's why I'm here asking for aid.

Comment: @Dxg125 Thanks a lot for this information. Let me sit down and do curry out some research. Just what I needed, this is all new to me.

Comment: @FelixSongwe you posted code for a `Create` component, and code for a `useFetch` custom hook. But the `Create` component isn't actually using the hook, it just calls fetch directly. So the two code chunks you posted are unrelated, at least as far as one can tell from just reading the code. It's even more of a problem because the error in the question title is likely coming from the hook, but you don't show the hook being used!

Comment: @JaredSmith I see were I went wrong. They are actually connected through my `App.js`. That's how I'm able to get that `abort error` When trying to create a new lead. The code contains multiple files and I created a custom SQL database to store all my blogs on my local computer. I just don't know how to show an overall view of my project since I'm new to stack overflow and pictures are discouraging because they seem to get down voted. Thanks for the advice highly appreciated.