# Angular2 , How to prevent from HTTP redirection

Tags: javascript, http, redirect, angular

I am trying to simulating user login by angular2 Http. let describe situation as bellow.
i have a php application that users can login throw `http://sample.com/login.php` url (a form exist with username and password input, user should fill inputs and press submit button)  and if login is success, they redirect to `http://sample.com/dashboard.php`. 
so i create a `Http` post with a form data that has "username" and "password" within.
and set Http header `content-type` as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.
login works fine and request automatically redirect to `http://sample.com/dashboard.php` .
 **problem** is that  i need to access **first request response header(http://sample.com/login.php)**, but the Http response me the second request response header  (http://sample.com/dashboard.php).
is that any way to prevent Http from redirecting? or throw error on status 302 ?

```
var headers = new Headers({'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'});
var options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
Http.post("http://sample.com/login.php",'username=admin&password=123' , options)
    .subscribe(success => {
        // success and return redirected response
        // response of http://sample.com/dashboard.php
    }, error => {
        // error handler
    }
);
```

Comment: did you check success.status ?

Comment: @A.T. its return 200, status of redirect request

Comment: @Shadow Wizard I would not consider this an *exact* duplicate. This question is specific to Angular 2, so marking this as a duplicate would imply that everyone stumbling upon this question do know that Angular 2's HTTP service uses XMLHttpRequest under the hood. I highly doubt this - otherwise the >1000 viewers of this question could have searched for HXMLHttpRequest directly and would have never landed here. IMO the right answer is that Angular's HTTP service uses XMLHttpRequest (along with a link to the question you marked as duplicate)

Comment: @emrass thanks for the thorough explanation, you raise valid points. Reopened.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible because XMLHttpRequest (low level API) does not expose such a method.

For more details look at this:

[Prevent redirection of Xmlhttprequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228225/prevent-redirection-of-xmlhttprequest)

Comment: That's a duplicate, next time better flag.