# How to view the http response redirect and history using ajax with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am currently using the python `requests` module which can easily show the response's redirect history:

```
>>> r = requests.get('http://github.com')
>>> r.history
[<Response [301]>]
```

I wish to know, if it is also possible to view this in jQuery by Ajax? In addition, is it possible to disable the redirection?

Comment: which redirection ? To see ajax calls you can in your browser press F12 and open Network tab. There are all files you call/ed with response, method, headers etc..

Comment: @FilipKováč I mean whether the page I requested redirect me to another page. I know in the browser I can check all the requests and response I made, but I would like to program depending on the redirect history.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent redirection of Xmlhttprequest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228225/prevent-redirection-of-xmlhttprequest)

Comment: @Dekel I can't find the answer to my question there.

Comment: The answer is that you can't (no access, no prevent). Sorry.