# How to make JQuery AJAX not follow the redirect after the successful form submission?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cors

> Failed to load http://example.com/signup.ashx: Redirect from 'http://example.com/signup.ashx' to 'http://0.0.0.0:8000/?result=success' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://0.0.0.0:8000' is therefore not allowed access.

How to make `jquery` `ajax` not follow the redirect after the successful form submission?

Basically my `ajax` call is a success, but because of the CORS error `ajax.fail()` is called instead of the `ajax.done()`.

It seems that `ajax` follow redirects [transparently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/343359/2146346) and that there were some considerations to add the methods allowing to override this behavior...

My code is really straightforward:

```
form.on("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: data
    }).done(function(data) {
        // do something on success
    }).fail(function(data) {
        // do something on failure
    });
});
```

It is a trivial task if one has access to both - the `backend` as well as the `frontend`, but it's quite a challenge if one has to deal with the remote API.

I do wonder, why on the *2nd* decade of the *21th* century (the time, when those other servers are just as important as our own) `JQuery` still has this problem?

Comment: cors is a middleware, so it will fail before getting to the success. What is happening

Comment: Can you elaborate more?

Comment: If you do not have cross-origin-access, on your headers, the post method from server will not be called. It will get there and return failing. You need to fix cors

Comment: @VictorOliveira This is what I state in the question - CORS Error. I have no control of the third party server, hence I cannot control CORS.

Comment: If they have cross-origin-access, you just need to set it in your headers from request. If they do not accept cross-origin-access, then you can not do much about it.

Comment: Can you elaborate more, like in the answer to the question?

Comment: try adding `crossDomain: true,` to your request, together with url and type. and see if changes something. Also, I need to know more about your problem to help with. I do not know what is happening with your cors.

Comment: @VictorOliveira what other information do you need, apart from what I already posted?

Comment: This is the domain you are requesting to? If you can check if the domain has cors enabled or not would be very useful. I am not sure if you can do something if cors is not enabled

Comment: @VictorOliveira Popular web-servers like apache/nginx does not add http header like `Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"` by default. The domain I'm trying to access doesn't have this problem either. Hence CORS Error.

Answer (score -1):

You can stop javascript propagation, if you don't have any other tasks running. It will start again at any user action.

The old and robust way:

```
window.stop() // Stop all js in the window context
```

Using a `try..catch` would be better.

```
try{
     // ajax stuff here
}
catch(nope){ console.log(nope) } // No errors
```

Or we can also throw a (new) error, this will exit your task with a warning. It can be useful in some cases for simplication.

```
throw "Error!"; // ⚠ Error! (Task stopped when thrown)
```

For your exact query, the [fetch api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/redirected) has a `Disallowing redirects` capability:

```
fetch("awesome-picture.jpg", { redirect: "error" }).then(function(response) {
  return response.blob();
}).then(function(imageBlob) {
  let imgObjectURL = URL.createObjectURL(imageBlob);
  document.getElementById("img-element-id").src = imgObjectURL;
});
```

See also [fetch()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch)

Comment: I tried this approach. With the `{ redirect: "error" }` setting I get the error (*no surprise*), so it's not ideal as I need redirects be silently ignored. Therefore I've tried `{ redirect: "manual" }`, in which case I can test `response.status` code, but presumably because the redirect hasn't been completed I get weird status code which is equal to `0`, again it's not ideal as it doesn't tell me much what happened to my `post` request.

Comment: Sad it can't help. Anyway it should be easily resolvable server side, like with php-curl.