# How do I use this.$http.post wihtout redirect in a method of a Vue component?

Tags: vue.js, vue-resource

I request from a method in a Vue component with `this.$http`  (from https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource) like this:

```
this.$http.post("/some/url", data).then(response => { ... })
```

In some cases the response may have status code `302 Found` and I want to process it in the callback in `then`. But instead the `this.$http.post` follows the location URL provided by the first response that is not desired. How do I force `this.$http.post` not to redirect?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prevent redirection of Xmlhttprequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228225/prevent-redirection-of-xmlhttprequest)

Comment: Note that vue-resource is [internally using](https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource/blob/1b2d0c94e0b5b4efbbbb136987401423b84e8cba/src/http/client/index.js#L62) XHR - that's the reason why I linked that answer